# TeXstudio/MiKTeX vs. TeXstudio/TeXlive. Which option is potentially less troublesome on Linux?

Tags: miktex, texlive, texstudio, linux

A few years ago I installed TeXstudio alongside with either MiKTeX or TeXlive on Linux. I remember it required so much tweaking to get it working with TeXstudio that I finally gave up and installed the other distribution which «paired» with TeXstudio without any hassle.

Now I need to install LaTeX on fresh Lubuntu. The problem is that I can't remember which one of the two distributions caused me so much headache (I love TexStudio and I am not prepared to trade it for another editor, no matter how well the latter goes with any LaTeX distribution).

If you happened to run into similar kind of troubles with TeXstudio and one of the distributions, please share your experience.

Comment: Unless you need bleeding edge package updates you can probably just get TeXLive directly from your Linux dist and that will work with texstudio out of the box. If your Linux dist is slow on TeXLive updates I'd use Upstream TeXLive, it requires a little extra settings.

Comment: @daleif Yes, you are right. But only if TeXlive is installed via apt on Ubuntu. Using its own installer may result in getting problems with TeXstudio (it did for me). The one installed via apt works in concert with TeXstudio without any tweaking, though.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. It is very easy to use upstream texlive on Linux and works without a problem with texstudio. But you need to set the PATH variavl manually and correctly and many fail this part